# Trouble installing cx_Oracle - Python?

Tags: python, python-import, cx-oracle, dpi

I have been trying to install cx_Oracle using PyCharm, it was installed successfully but I import and run the script I get the following error:

```
DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you read the document named in the error message?

Comment: Yes, but still unable to solve the error after following the steps

Answer (score 1):

It is now referring to the instance client for oracle that you will need to point to in your code.

Please read the [the docs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html).

The code should look something like this:

```
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_19_6")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to point the client to your code so that it can connect to Oracle databases. Try this:

1. Install the library using `pip`

```py
pip install cx_Oracle
```

2. Import the library and use its function `init_oracle_client` to
   point to a file as the client.

```py
import cx_Oracle as oc

oc.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r<your path>)
```